Unable to Retrieve Page Access Token with System User Access Token in Facebook App: Only Page ID Returned
I have a Facebook app running in production, and I've created a system user within Facebook Business Manager. After generating a system user access token, I have also generated a user access token for the system user. However, the API response only returns the page ID and not the page access token. What steps should I take to ensure that the system user has the necessary permissions, and how can I retrieve the page access token successfully?
I generated a system user access token and used it to call the Facebook Graph API to retrieve the page access token. I expected the API to return the page access token, but instead, it only returned the page ID. I was expecting the access_token field in the response but did not receive it.
Here is the CURL used to fetch the page access token :
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{page_id}?fields=access_token&access_token={user_access_token_or_system_user_access_token}"

What role does the system user have on the page?

Hi had same problem. I solved it changing the "User or page" field to "Get the access identifier to the page"
NOTE: I have mine in Spanish, so maybe your API Graph isn't identical.
I hope it works for you.
